# "directory not found for option" Flurry Analytics Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, flurry

Whenever I reopen my XCode project, I always get these errors cause by the flurry analytics library:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/...'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LFiles/Flurry'
ld: library not found for -lFlurry_5.0.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

At first, when the project is opened, it will not build, then if I drag the flurry library to frameworks (even though it is already visibly there), it will build, but there will still be the two warnings.

If I delete the library search paths, then the error and warnings go away, but when I reopen the project, they always come back.

Is there anyway to fix this so the warnings are not always there and I don't have to re-add the library every time I open the project?

Answer (score 3):

There is a reference issue with the library.

1. Remove existing references in the library search paths.
2. Remove the Library if present inside the Project folder.
3. Copy the Library inside the project folder say "Flurry".
4. Reference the library as a relative path (not absolute) in library search path as "$(SRCROOT)/Flurry"

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for a great answer. My problem was that I had like 10 different search paths for ever time I tried to add flurry. Gotta kill them all!